# How to efficiently find a specific substring in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, substring

OK, I know how to do this but I'm interested in better/more elegant solutions (if any) for this problem.

Imagine I have the following string :

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; **MSIE 7.0**;
>   Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6.6;
>   Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; **MSIE 6.0**;
>   Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; .NET CLR
>   1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)

I'm interested to find the highest MSIE version in that string (in that case 7.0).

Currently I use explode and preg_match a couple of times in combination with str_replace then I loop between matches and then compare the version string. It works but it's far from elegant. Any ideas on how to improve this?

Keep in mind that:

- The string can have any number of MSIE occurrences (or even none)
- MSIE is case insensitive
- MSIE is followed by a white space (space, tab...) then by the version. The version can contain number letters and dots. The version string is ended by either a white space, a ; or the end of the line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
$str = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6.6; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1), MSIE 8.7abc; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729) MSIE 9.0';

if (preg_match_all('/msie\s*([^\s;$]+)/i', $str, $m)) {
    usort($m[1], 'version_compare');
    $max = array_pop($m[1]);

    echo $max;
}
```

Comment: How would I modify preg_match_all to fit my last point in my bullet point list (see question)?

Comment: Yes almost... I only need the white space between MSIE and the version string to be optional.

Comment: Edited again, see the \s* instead of \s+

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to implement browser detection, [it's a lot more complex than this](http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/).

Comment: Yes, I know and I'm asking this because I'm rewriting some part of this very lib :) Chris' class is unreliable on some very weird UAs.

Answer (score 1):

This work may have already been done for you.

You may want to look up PHP's [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function, along with the related `browsecap.ini` file.

However, I would generally advise that doing browser detection is generally a bad idea. It is fundamentally unreliable because the browser can fake its user agent string. And even if the browser doesn't do it, it can still be changed or blanked out by proxies and security software.

Comment: Yes I know, I'm working on updating an existing lib similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$str = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; msie 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6.6; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.1; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)";

preg_match_all('/MSIE\s([\d.]+);/i', $str, $matches);

if(!empty($matches[1])){
    echo "Max version found:" . max($matches[1]);
}else{
    echo "None found";
}
```

Comment: How would I modify preg_match_all to fit my last point in my bullet point list (see question)?

Answer (score 0):

stripos() does exactly what you are describing. I'm not sure how it can get any more efficient than than in PHP.

> Returns the numeric position of the first occurrence of needle in the haystack  string.
>    Unlike strpos(), stripos() is case-insensitive.

Comment: Just realized you wanted to capture the version number as well. You could potentially check the next few characters after the returned position to check for version, which would still probably be faster than preg family functions.